# Laravel server could not get response after a long amount of time

Tags: php, laravel, timeout, server

As introduction I'd like to give the basic codeflow of my laravel server.
Firstly, a Request is sent and processed. Based on the parameters of the request, a [Command](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/bus) is made and Pushed into a Queue using the Queue Facade.

> Queue::push($command);

After that my Queue will work on the command for some time and it works pretty well. I know it works because the correct entries are added to my sql database and a response is given when its done. The problem is when I push a command that takes a long time to process (longer than an hour but I'm not sure exactly how long) The server stops after a while. My Postman will eventually show me [this](http://puu.sh/iSlsI/e47dddeec9.png) and my database has some of the required entries filled but not all. I have checked my apache logs and there were no errors.

Is my server (or Queue) timing out? How can I check? Is there a laravel log for this?!

Comment: which provider do you use for Queue? Beanstalkd, IronMQ, Amazon SQS, Redis? or is it just synchronous?

Comment: Im not to certain on how to check

Comment: `config/queue.php` see the line 
   `'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync'),`